# Why is Russia not considered a European Country?

Tags: russian-federation, europe, soviet-union

[Russia looks very much like mainland Europe, it dresses like mainland Europe, but it is not considered part of Europe](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2625948). This is not a recent phenomenon. Even since the time of the Tzar's, especially Peter the Great, Russia was somehow considered not part of Europe. One of the goals of Tzar Peter, was to [make Russia more European, by taxing beards and banning Russian style clothing](https://daily.jstor.org/peter-the-greats-beard-tax/).

Another plausible pattern is that countries and cultures that use a Latin or its derivative scripts are somehow considered more European than countries that use Cyrillic scripts. Is this causation or simply correlation?

Most of the Russian population lives on the European Continent. The politics of Russia is decided by those living on the European Continent. The Russian Empire has had German queens.

Having said that, the distinction stands, and this effort from the peoples of Slavic origin to prove themselves European continues till this day.

Is this due to the schism between the Russian Orthodox church to the Catholic Church which ruled continental Europe and would decide who became king in the Holy Roman Empire as opposed to the Tzar of Russia who appointed the synod of the Russian Orthodox church?

What is the reason for this geo-political pattern between the peoples of Russia and the peoples of Europe?

Comment: "Not considered part of Europe" by whom, and in what way? Geographically, Russia is part of both Europe and Asia, much as Turkey is, but as far as I'm aware it's treated as part of Europe for most purposes. It's a member of the Council of Europe, the Organization for Security and Co-operation in Europe (go figure), UEFA, and so on.

Comment: I don't have access to the source you linked to, but from the title and the abstract, I assume it literally answers your question. So, what part of it do you not understand?

Comment: @F1Krazy Please go through the hyperlinks in the question. The hyperlinks point out by whom and in what way Russia is not considered part of Europe.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It focuses only on the present, post WW2. I want a more historical perspective. My question is not about today or now, it is about the historical pattern, hence the mention of Peter, the Great and his effort to Europeanize Russia by banning beards, forcing French clothes etc.

Comment: @ksinkar As Jörg W Mittag noted, the first link is paywalled and can't actually be read, and the second alludes to Peter the Great wanting to "Europeanise" Russia but never states that Russia was not considered part of Europe at the time. Questions on Stack Exchange should be standalone, because links tend to die out over time. Please summarise the relevant information from the linked articles inside your question.

Comment: @F1Krazy Why would Peter, the Great want to Europeanise Russia, if it was already considered part of Europe? Wouldn't Russian customs, clothes etc. be already by definition be European if Russia was considered part of Europe?

Answer (score 1):

The **considering** is very much in the eye of the beholder, and sometimes an attempt to *make* political facts.

- The most egregious example is the Nazi ideology which defined Russians as [Untermensch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untermensch) to justify taking their land as [Lebensraum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebensraum) for non-Untermenschen.
- Some people view Russia as in the grip of [Oriental Despotism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriental_Despotism), which is subtly defined as not properly European.
- A more real difference would be the one between [Orthodox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Orthodox_Church) and non-Orthodox Christianity, and also between Slavs and non-Slavs. The astute observer might note that there are plenty of Slavs and Orthodox Christians in South-Eastern Europe, but then from a Western European bias they are "somewhat on the fringe," too. Not as much as the Russians, maybe.
- And then there is the relatively late end of [serfdom and slavery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serfdom_in_Russia).

Russia stands poised between Europe and Asia. Both Russian leaders and Europeans may try to sway perceptions and reality one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Russia originated from Europe and they spanned east also they had Alaska but it was sold. About 80 percent of Russian population lives in the European part of Russia and it makes Russia the most populous country in Europe also Russian are white European or Slavic. Russia is a European country because of it origin and because it’s official classified or certified as European by the United Nations.
Facts or official statistics:
https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/countries-in-europe/

https://www.worldometers.info/geography/how-many-countries-in-europe/

Answer (score -3):

It depends on the criteria you use:

Linguistically, Russian is a Slavic tongue, closely related to European languages such as Polish and Czech. Most Russians have European names like Victor, Alexander, Peter, Anna, Yulia or Katerina, rather than Arabic or Sanskrit names.

Religiously, it is a majority Christian nation, and the Russian Orthodox Church is closer to Catholic beliefs than say Evangelicals.

Historically, Russia had more ties with European powers than with China or the Muslim Middle East, and even boasted to be "Third Rome"

So according to the above criteria, Russia is European. However, Russia's political culture is certainly not European. Modern Europe is defined by its democracy and respect for the rights of the individual. This is certainly not the case with Putin's regime. There are of course many individuals in Russia who stand for European political values. One of them is tweeting from a gulag.

Also, see the following article:
https://www.rbth.com/lifestyle/331166-russia-part-of-europe